# How to validate/test the Google My Business APIs with more than 200 locations?

Tags: google-my-business-api

I am a backend developer in a SaaS startup. I wish to test all possible responses from the exposed Google My Business APIs. I have set up a test account with 2 locations, however, I would like to test for 200 or more locations. I am wondering how others tested their code while developing their product using Google My Business APIs. (I would like to test scenarios like fetching more than 100 locations associated to a single account)

Comment: How did you set up the locations? I have a Place ID, but can't find how to do it. I know this doesn't help with your question, but I've spent considerable time dealing with this issue, so thought I'd ask.

Comment: @BrianGottier - To tell you frankly, the locations that are the part of the test account are actual physical locations that were verified offline and belong to the startup I work in.